# PHP Ghostscript error, but command line works fine (decoding pdf to png)

Tags: php, ghostscript

I'm executing this command from command line:

```
gs -sOutputFile=- -sDEVICE=pnggray -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r90 -q /Volumes/DATA/03-www/temp/test.pdf -c quit
```

And it works fine, decoding the pdf to png. But then I execute this code from php:

```
$cmd = "gs -sOutputFile=- -sDEVICE=pnggray -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r90 -q " . $pdf_file . " -c quit";
$img = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I get null response. I appended `2>&1` to $cmd to see errors:

```
$cmd = "gs -sOutputFile=- -sDEVICE=pnggray -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -dNOPAUSE -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r90 -q " . $pdf_file . " -c quit 2>&1";
```

And the output is the following one:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.16.dylib
  Reason: Incompatible library version: libgs.9.16.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libtiff.5.dylib provides version 6.0.0
```

Ghostscript version gives (cli):

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.16 (2015-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

Any help please?

Comment: Why are you setting the output file to STDOUT inside your PHP script (i.e. where does your converted file go?)?  Do you have multiple copies of Ghostscript on the system?  Does the output from `which gs` match when you run it from your CLI and from inside that PHP script?

Comment: I've set the STDOUT to get png data as the response of the script. In this way I don't have to write a temp file to read it later and delete it after all. `which gs` has the same location inside php and CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are using a build of Ghostscript which uses shared libraries, and the system can't find the libtiff 8 dynamic library.

You appear to have libtiff 5 installed, you need libtiff 8. Presumably libtiff 8 is installed for your user, but not the PHP user which is why it works for you from the command line.

Or you can use a build of Ghostscript which doesn't use shared libraries, but that will mean building it yourself as it looks like the packager for your distro has chosen to use shared libraries.